# Creating a javascript notes app but note prints more than once?

Tags: javascript, class, dom

I am new to javascript. I am trying to creates a notesapp with notes made by user input. So far I am able to add and display the notes but each note is being displayed twice e.g if I input "hello" it prints hello but then if I then input "goodbye" it prints out "hello,hello,goodbye." I have my code printed below with my view and model class.

```
class NotesView{
    constructor(model){
        this.model = model;
        this.mainContainerEL = document.querySelector('#main-container');
        this.noteButton = document.querySelector('#add-note');

        this.noteButton.addEventListener('click', () => { this.addNewNote() });
    }
    

    addNewNote(){
        const new_note = document.getElementById('message').value;
        
        this.model.addNote(new_note);

        this.displayNotes();
      
    }

    displayNotes() {     
        const notes = this.model.getNotes();
       
        notes.forEach(note =>{
            
            const noteEl = document.createElement('div'); 
            noteEl.textContent = note;                    
            noteEl.className = 'note';                   
            this.mainContainerEL.append(noteEl);        
        })
        
    }
}
module.exports = NotesView;

class notesModel{
    constructor(notes){
        this.notes = []
    }

    getNotes(){
        return this.notes
    }

    addNote(note){
       return this.notes.push(note)
    }
    
    reset(){
        this.notes.splice(0, this.notes.length)
    }

}

module.exports = notesModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not *"resetting"* the DOM. Everytime you click the button `addNewNote()` will be called which calls `displayNotes()`. `displayNotes()` will always create a new div for all elements in the `notes` array and append that div to the `#main-container` element.

So on first click on the button the array will contain `hello` and one `div` to display hello will be appended to the container. So far, so good.

Now on the second click you will add another element to the array so it will contain `["hello", "goodbye"]`. And you will create another two divs for those to elements and append that to the container. The container therefore now has three element: the *hello* div from the first click and a *hello* and *goodbye* div from the second click, that's why you'll see `hello, hello, goodbye`.

Here a minimal example showcasing the error:

```js
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => addSecondNote())
const notes = ["hello", "goodbye"];

function addSecondNote(){
  const container = document.querySelector("#container");
  notes.forEach(note => {
    const noteDiv = document.createElement("div");
    noteDiv.textContent = note;
    container.append(noteDiv);
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Add a second note</button>
<div id="container">
  <div>hello<span> 
<div/>
```

One of many possible ways to resolve this is to use [`replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) which will take an [Iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) of [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) or `string` as a parameter. You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of the child `div`s.

```js
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => addSecondNote())
const notes = ["hello", "goodbye"];

function addSecondNote(){
  const container = document.querySelector("#container");
  const newChildDivs = notes.map(note => {
    const noteDiv = document.createElement("div");
    noteDiv.textContent = note;
    return noteDiv;
  });
  container.replaceChildren(...newChildDivs);
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Add a second note</button>
<div id="container">
  <div>hello<span> 
<div/>
```

Comment: thank you, I understand the concept much better

Answer (score 0):

as Mushroomator said you are appending the whole model notes each time you add a note.
so you either

- clear the container before adding all those notes.
- display the new notes as soon as you add them to the model.
- add an index to the model to only display the newest notes
  the index solution is something like this

```js
class NotesView {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.mainContainerEL = document.querySelector("#main-container");
    this.noteButton = document.querySelector("#add-note");
    this.noteButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.addNewNote();
    });
  }

  addNewNote() {
    const new_note = document.getElementById("message").value;

    this.model.addNote(new_note);

    this.displayNotes();
  }

  displayNotes() {
    const notes = this.model.getNotes();
    for (let i = this.model.displayindex; i < notes.length; i++) {
      const noteEl = document.createElement("div");
      noteEl.textContent = notes[i];
      noteEl.className = "note";
      this.mainContainerEL.append(noteEl);
      this.model.displayindex++;
    }
  }
}

class notesModel {
  constructor(notes) {
    this.notes = [];
    this.displayindex = 0;
  }

  getNotes() {
    return this.notes;
  }

  addNote(note) {
    return this.notes.push(note);
  }

  reset() {
    this.notes.splice(0, this.notes.length);
    this.displayindex = 0;
  }
}
let myNotes = new NotesView(new notesModel())
```

```html
<button id="add-note">Add a second note</button>
<input type="text" id="message"/>
<div id="main-container">
  <div>hello<span> 
<div/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class NotesView {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.mainContainerEL = document.querySelector("#main-container");
    this.noteButton = document.querySelector("#add-note");
    this.noteButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.addNewNote();
    });
  }

  addNewNote() {
    const new_note = document.getElementById("message").value;

    this.model.addNote(new_note);

    this.displayNotes();
  }

  displayNotes() {
    const notes = this.model.getNotes();
    for (let i = this.model.displayindex; i < notes.length; i++) {
      const noteEl = document.createElement("div");
      noteEl.textContent = notes[i];
      noteEl.className = "note";
      this.mainContainerEL.append(noteEl);
      this.model.displayindex++;
    }
  }
}

class notesModel {
  constructor(notes) {
    this.notes = [];
    this.displayindex = 0;
  }

  getNotes() {
    return this.notes;
  }

  addNote(note) {
    return this.notes.push(note);
  }

  reset() {
    this.notes.splice(0, this.notes.length);
    this.displayindex = 0;
  }
}
let myNotes = new NotesView(new notesModel())
```

```html
<button id="add-note">Add a second note</button>
<input type="text" id="message"/>
<div id="main-container">
  <div>hello<span> 
<div/>
```